# Ifelse statement : if the strings starts or ends with a particular set of characters, delete them

Tags: r, string, if-statement, substring

I'm trying to remove some characters from the strings, but for some reason my code doesn't seem to work. I have the following data

```
data <- as.data.frame (structure(list(col_name = c("applexz", "Jack", "Tablesxz", "aorange"))))
    
col_name

applexz
Jack
Tablexz
aorange
```

and I'm trying to tell R to remove the last two characters if the last two characters are "xz"
(I want to repeat it with other strings and numbers of characters later, for example removing the first character if it is 'a', as in the 'aorange' here)
But when I try different options nothing happens, or it prints "NO" in each column, not detecting the substring - where is the problem?

```
data$col2 <- ifelse (str_sub(data$col_name,  -1) == "xz", str_sub(data$col_name,1, nchar(data$col_name))-2, data$col_name) #this is to remove the last two characters if the condition is met

data$col2 <- ifelse (str_sub(data$col_name,  -1) == "xz", 'YES', 'NO')

data$col2 <- ifelse(grepl('^xz', data$col_name), 'YES', 'NO')
```

Comment: If you run just `str_sub(data$col_name,  -1)` you'll see it gives the last character, not the last two characters.

Answer (score 3):

A simple regular expression can do this much simpler:

```r
sub("xz$", "", data$col_name)
# [1] "apple"   "Jack"    "Tables"  "aorange"
```

But to your code:

- `str_sub(., -1)` is returning the last letter only, you should check the inner values your code is using before assuming `ifelse` will know what to do with it:

  ```r
  stringr::str_sub(data$col_name, -1)
  # [1] "z" "k" "z" "e"

  ifelse(stringr::str_sub(data$col_name, -2) == "xz", 'YES', 'NO')
  # [1] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"
  ```
- your regex for `grepl` is looking at the beginning (`^`) instead of the end (`$`) of the string.

  ```r
  grepl("xz$", data$col_name)
  # [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ifelse(grepl('xz$', data$col_name), 'YES', 'NO')
  # [1] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to delete a particular set of characters if the string starts OR ends with them:

```r
mylist <- c("applexz", "xzJack", "Tablesxz", "aorange")
sub("^xz|xz$", "", mylist)
# [1] "apple"   "Jack"    "Tables"  "aorange"
```

With one use of sub, you are deleting the characters if the strings starts ("^xz") OR ends ("xz$") with them. I believe this answers the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

str_sub() will recycle all arguments to be the same length as the longest argument. You need to use

```
str_sub(data$col_name, start=-2, end=-1)
```

to indicate the last two characters. I am not sure how str_sub() can substitute substrings for a whole data.frame, but for a single element in data.frame, you could write a for loop to substitute all tail "xz"

```
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  if(str_sub(data[i],  -2,-1) == "xz")
    str_sub(data[2],  -2,-1) <- ""
}
```

You can also try function like gsub() or sub()

```
sub("xz","",data$col_name)
```

This method has a potential drawback that it will substitute all "xz"s found in your data.frame

For example, if you have an extra entry "xzdef", the function will also turn "xzdef" to "def".

Comment: this is actually the best way I think, although it doesn't work if the word has more than one specified string (e.g. "a" in the beginning and "xz" at the end), but I can probably do an iteration with & to check if that makes a difference